# NativeScript: Virtual module path mapping

Tags: typescript, nativescript, node-modules

Is it possible to use module path mapping in NativeScript at runtime?

The TypeScript [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) 'paths' allows to map virtual module ids to physical ones. If, for example, one needs to require the module `node_modules/my_package/dist/commonjs/my_modules/my_module` it is possible to define a mapping and then require the virtual module `my_modules/my_module` instead:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "my_modules/*": [ "node_modules/my_package/dist/commonjs/my_modules/*" ]
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine at compile time but the TypeScript compiler won't emit the resolved module ids. Instead, it leaves the specified (virtual) module ids in place. As a result, the modules will not be found at runtime.

There is a node package called [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) that adresses this issue in a nodejs environment. However, I was not able to set this up in the NativeScript runtime.

Comment: It does already work with NativeScript, in fact with the previous versions of NativeScript a similar default settings (`"./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*"`) was used to import any module from `tns-core-modules` without referring the package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across the same issue, here's the thing:

After upgrading to NativeScript's new [bundle workflow](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/the-future-of-building-nativescript-apps) the issue was solved by simply adding the respective mapping to the webpack.config.js:

```js
const config = {
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      "my_modules/*": "node_modules/my_package/dist/commonjs/my_modules/*"
    ]
  }
}
```